# What is the difference between these articulations?

Tags: articulation

What is the difference in playing between *accent* (the little right pointing arrow,) *staccato* (the little dot,) *marcato* (the little hat,) *accent-staccato* (the little right-pointing arrow with the little dot under it,) and *marcato-staccato* (the little hat with the little dot under it)?

(I've tried consulting standard sources and can't find a clear explanation of the differences; all the sources I've seen seem to assume the reader already knows.)

Comment: Welcome! 1) The practical differences can be very different for different instruments. Please use the "edit" button to say whether you're thinking of one instrument in particular. 2) Be warned, even if there are "official" answers, these symbols have been used for centuries with some inconsistencies and overlaps. There's a lot of gray area. Any *interpreter* has to ask "what exactly did the composer mean." Any composer has to ask "what will the interpreter *think* I mean?"

Comment: The most universal underlying principle here, though, is distinguishing between the *duration* of the note and the *loudness* of the note. Note, also, on instruments that can shape the volume after attack, an accent doesn't just mean "louder note"; it's like a tiny decrescendo; it means that the *start* of the note should be emphasized.

Comment: If you specify the instrument it will be easier to answer. The answers are slightly different for different instruments.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing for some ambiguity based on the composer and era, here are the general rules:

- **accent**: play the note a bit louder than the surrounding context.
- **staccato**: although the note is allotted its usual amount of time, the sounding portion of the note is short. Some consider that in baroque era music, the note should be given half its normal length. Thus, a staccato quarter note would sound the same as an eighth note followed by an eighth rest.
- **marcato**: played with a sharp attack, but not as strongly as a full accent.
- **accent-staccato**: the sounding portion of the note is short and also played louder than the surrounding context.
- **marcato-staccato**: played even shorter than a "regular" staccato, with some accent.

Answer (score 0):

An *accent* or sometimes called *sforzando* marks the note to be played stronger or harder. A *staccato* means the note should not be played for the whole length, but shortened. A *marcato* means "marked", which means you should emphasize the note, the note should stand out.

Any combination of such markings is exactly that: Accent+Staccato is a short, strong note, marcato and staccato is a short, emphasized note.